# how to save excel file in my local directory in php with out downloading

Tags: php, excel

I am working in Cms if any customer click and save the excel file  they should get download in browser at the same time another copy save in to my server folder. 
the below codings only helps to download for customer i want to know how to save another copy in my local server

```
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

thanks in advance

Comment: save excel file with out downloading ? what it means?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by saving without downloading?  Do you wish to save it to the server?  Show it in the browser?  What?

Comment: i want to save in my local directory at run time not by browser

Answer (score 0):

The headers really have nothing to do with creating or saving a file on the server. The headers only tell the browser how to interpret the content.

Take a look at [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for a good resource on creating Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

first, you execute your script that make the excel file (you save the temp file somewhere) a

```
$my_excel_content = file_get_content("http://myserver/make_excel.php?parameters=...");
$my_excel_filename = "/tmp/".md5(session_id().microtime(TRUE)).".xls";
file_put_content($my_excel_filename,$my_excel_content);
```

Add your file name with absolute path

**OR**

use using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), you can use like below

```
$objWriter->save('nameoffile.xls');
```

hope this will solve yourissue

Comment: can you please say where i give the location to save the file

Comment: $my_excel_filename = "/tmp/".md5(session_id().microtime(TRUE)).".xls"; this will be your path